# Upload large video file use Retrofit(Android) have OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, upload, retrofit

Sorry for my English. I try to upload large video file on the server, this file more than 50 mb. When i upload small files, all works fine. In the manifest i set `android:largeHeap="true"` and `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` its not help me. Below is my code:

Interface

```
@Multipart
@POST("/api/upload")
Observable<UploadVideoResponse> uploadVideo(@Header("Authorization") String userToken,
                                            @Part MultipartBody.Part video);
```

method return file:

```
public static MultipartBody.Part getMultipartVideoBody(String pathVideo) {
    try {
        File videoFile = getFile(pathVideo);
        RequestBody videoBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("video/*"), videoFile);
        String fileName = videoFile.getName();
        return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("video", fileName, videoBody);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("File ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

method upload on server

```
new DefaultApi().uploadVideo(
                Utils.getHeaderToken(),
                Utils.getMultipartVideoBody(pathVideo)
        ).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnSubscribe(videoView::showLoading)
                .doOnTerminate(videoView::hideLoading)
                .subscribe(data -> {
                            videoView.setData(data);
                        }
                        , throwable -> {

                        }
                );
    }
```

ERROR:

> Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 100390006 byte
>   allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 92MB until OOM"

FULL stacktrace

> 09-11 03:53:00.571 6724-6976/des.brain.ga E/art: Throwing
>   OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 100390006 byte allocation with
>   16777216 free bytes and 92MB until OOM" 09-11 03:53:00.573
>   6724-6976/des.brain.ga E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   RxIoScheduler-3
>       Process: des.brain.ga, PID: 6724
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread.
>           at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:59)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>        Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 100390006 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 92MB until OOM
>           at java.lang.String.(String.java:332)
>           at java.lang.String.(String.java:371)
>           at okio.Buffer.readString(Buffer.java:620)
>           at okio.Buffer.readString(Buffer.java:603)
>           at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:199)
>           at des.brain.ga.api.base.LoggingInterceptor.intercept(LoggingInterceptor.java:31)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
>           at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
>           at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
>           at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
>           at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallExecuteOnSubscribe.call(CallExecuteOnSubscribe.java:40)
>           at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallExecuteOnSubscribe.call(CallExecuteOnSubscribe.java:24)
>           at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.BodyOnSubscribe.call(BodyOnSubscribe.java:36)
>           at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.BodyOnSubscribe.call(BodyOnSubscribe.java:28)
>           at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>           at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:100)
>           at rx.internal.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(CachedThreadScheduler.java:230)
>           at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)  09-11 03:53:02.159 6724-6724/des.brain.ga E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked:
>   Activity des.brain.ga.ui.main.HomeActivity has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{2ccb16a1
>   V.ED.... R.....ID 0,0-144,144} that was originally added here
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
>           at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
>           at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>           at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
>           at com.kaopiz.kprogresshud.KProgressHUD.show(KProgressHUD.java:233)
>           at des.brain.ga.ui.video.UploadVideoFragment.showLoading(UploadVideoFragment.java:150)
>           at des.brain.ga.ui.video.VideoPresenter$$Lambda$4.call(Unknown Source)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnSubscribe.call(OperatorDoOnSubscribe.java:40)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnSubscribe.call(OperatorDoOnSubscribe.java:27)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:44)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>           at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
>           at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10352)
>           at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10319)
>           at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10159)
>           at des.brain.ga.ui.video.VideoPresenter.uploadVideo(VideoPresenter.java:65)
>           at des.brain.ga.ui.video.UploadVideoFragment.lambda$uploadVideo$0$UploadVideoFragment(UploadVideoFragment.java:127)
>           at des.brain.ga.ui.video.UploadVideoFragment$$Lambda$0.onClick(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.afollestad.materialdialogs.MaterialDialog.onClick(MaterialDialog.java:410)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

**LoggingInterceptor**

```
public final class LoggingInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private final Interceptor mLoggingInterceptor;

    private LoggingInterceptor() {
        mLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor()
                //.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? Level.BODY : Level.NONE);
    }

    @NonNull
    public static Interceptor create() {
        return new LoggingInterceptor();
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        return mLoggingInterceptor.intercept(chain);
    }

}
```

and i use `LoggingInterceptor` like this:

```
return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(LoggingInterceptor.create())
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .build();
```

Comment: whats the full stacktrace?

Comment: @pskink i update my question

Comment: `des.brain.ga.api.base.LoggingInterceptor` is it yours?

Comment: @pskink yes, i upd question

Comment: remove, just for testing, those `.addInterceptor()` methods when creating `OkHttpClient.Builder` - if it works remove only one and check which one makes your problems

Comment: @pskink I am shocked. Thanks wary match! Why did it work without them?

Comment: which one makes problems? `.addInterceptor(LoggingInterceptor.create())`? or the other one?

Comment: @pskink works only if I remove two`.addInterceptor`s video upload success. This is strange for me

Comment: @r1299597 how did u passed token using Utils.getHeaderToken()?? Pls reply..

Comment: @KJEjava48 it just header for the request. In interface it looks like this: `@Multipart
    @POST("/api/upload")
    Observable<UploadVideoResponse> uploadVideo(@Header("Authorization") String userToken,
                                                @Part MultipartBody.Part video);`

Comment: @KJEjava48 my method: `public static String getHeaderToken() {
        String token = null;

        String t = HawkUtils.get_string_hawk(HawkUtils.key_access_token);
        //String tt = HawkUtils.get_string_hawk(HawkUtils.key_token_type);

        if (t != null) {
            token = "Bearer " + t;
            Log.e("token", token);
        }

        return token;
    }` its token from server. Its need for authorization

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have faced same error while uploading large video using retrofit,but
Removing
`loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)`
or set is as `NONE`
worked for me.

Comment: Your solution works great, as I can see, now if you debug the app, you won't see all the log from the requests and resposes right?

Comment: Yes this because we are setting Log level to NONE.

Comment: After removing this interceptor, still, I get the issue

Comment: Please provide more details of your error and code snippet?@ParthPatel

Comment: I search and see there is no options to have the logs in OkHttp with BODY Level in this case. and the library implementors said you can fork the library and change it as you want . and yes you won't have BODY log like before unfortunately.

Comment: Nice answer. Yeah useful when upload large video via multipart API using Retrofit set below property in ApiClient.
**interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);**