# Video upload failing with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

My users are able to upload videos.

I'm trying to upload the video to the server, but I'm getting this error for bigger videos:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 134217744 byte allocation with 100663296 free bytes and 118MB until OOM, target footprint 244429328, growth limit 268435456

Here is how I'm putting together my request with Retrofit:

```
MultipartBody.Part media = ApiHelper.prepareFilePart(this, "video", uri);

ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.createService(ApiInterface.class, this, PreferenceUtils.getAuthToken(this));

Call<BasicResponse> call = apiService.createVideoPost(
        media
);
call.enqueue(new Callback<BasicResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<BasicResponse> call, Response<BasicResponse> response) {
        //
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<BasicResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        //
    }
});
```

And here is the code from `ApiHelper`:

```
public class ApiHelper {

    @NonNull
    public static MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(Context context, String partName, Uri fileUri) {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);

            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

            RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse(context.getContentResolver().getType(fileUri)),
                    bytes
            );

            return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, String.valueOf(fileUri), requestFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

It's failing on this line:

```
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
```

I don't know how else to upload a file from a URI.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52270693/upload-large-video-file-use-retrofitandroid-have-outofmemoryerror

If you added logging interceptor set None or if you want track other api's create another retrofit instance only for uploading purpose.

Comment: @GobuCSG Unfortunately that didn't help, same error

Comment: See here.
https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/540

Can you share entire log here?